# What kind of function parameter is 'double (*bag)[VECT_SIZE]'?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

this is for a c++ programming assignment. The function prototype we are given to use has the following format:

```
void closestPair(double (*bag)[VEC_SIZE], int noVec, double *vecA, double *vecB)
```

I'm trying to figure out what kind of variable the (*bag)[VEC_SIZE] is. I've assumed its a pointer to an array of arrays, but everything I try to pass to it gets a "no matching function" error. I know 100% that this is the argument that I'm having trouble with. I thought it was a pointer to an array of arrays (which would make sense for what I'm trying to do with this function), but that doesn't seem to be working.

Also, here are the test values I'm trying to pass to this function, and where the function call is happening: If anyone could help me figure out how to pass these values to the function, and as well explain to me what kind of variable (*bag)[VECT_SIZE] is, that'd be great!

```
double a[10] = {
    0.183963, 0.933146, 0.476773, 0.086125, 0.566566, 0.728107, 0.837345, 0.885175, 0.600559, 0.142238
};
double b[10] = {
    0.086523, 0.025236, 0.252289, 0.089437, 0.382081, 0.420934, 0.038498, 0.626125, 0.468158, 0.247754
};
double c[10] = {
    0.969345, 0.127753, 0.736213, 0.264992, 0.518971, 0.216767, 0.390992, 0.242241, 0.516135, 0.990155
};

//Create and load test array
const int N = 3;
double arrays[3][10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arrays[0][i] = a[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arrays[1][i] = b[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    arrays[2][i] = c[i];
}

closestPair(arrays, N, a, b);
```

Comment: `T (*)[N]` is a pointer to an array. In this case `bag` is a pointer to an array of `VEC_SIZE` elements of type `double`. You need to pass the address of an array for it to work. It can't work with `&arrays` because that is a pointer to a two-dimensional array. Maybe you should iterate through and get the closest pair of each internal array.

Comment: Voila! Now you'll never need to wonder ever again: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: @Nick - I tried to narrow the title a bit. Please feel free to revert it.

Comment: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=double+%28*bag%29%5B10%5D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pointer to an array of VEC_SIZE doubles. This is the type that an array of X arrays of VEC_SIZE doubles decays to. In code:

```
double arr[X][VEC_SIZE] = { /* ... */ };
double a, b;
closestPair(arr, X, &a, &b);
```

You can also pass an address of a normal array:

```
double arr[VEC_SIZE];
double a, b;
closestPair(&arr, 1, &a, &b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the function correctly.

```
closestPair(arrays, N, a, b);
```

I think that the problem is that `VEC_SIZE` is not equal to 10. So either you have to redefine array `arrays` like

```
double arrays[3][VEC_SIZE];
```

or change the value of `VEC_SIZE` to 10.

Also if you defined constant `N` then it would be better to define `arrays` as

```
double arrays[N][VEC_SIZE];
```

Do not use magic numbers ( as 3 or 10 ) in your programs.

Comment: wow you're absolutely right! changing the size of VEC_SIZE to 10 fixed it. Thank you, much appreciated!